# array group_by converted date

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array:

```
array=[
{"name"=>"Henry Jones ", "Date"=>"2013-04-09 15:09:02", "Duration"=>"0:00:00", "Call Type"=>"Outgoing"},
{"name"=>"Barry Smith ", "Date"=>"2013-04-08 13:51:03", "Duration"=>"0:00:48", "Call Type"=>"Incoming"}, 
{"name"=>"Henry Jones ", "Date"=>"2013-04-04 19:30:19", "Duration"=>"0:00:49", "Call Type"=>"Outgoing"},
{"name"=>"Alistair Morgan ", "Date"=>"2013-04-05 13:14:07", "Duration"=>"0:00:03", "Call Type"=>"Outgoing"}, 
{"name"=>"Quentin Blah", "Date"=>"2013-04-05 13:19:44", "Duration"=>"0:04:28", "Call Type"=>"Missed"}, 
{"name"=>"Quentin Blah", "Date"=>"2013-04-05 13:25:19", "Duration"=>"0:09:45", "Call Type"=>"Incoming"}, 
{"name"=>"Henry Jones ", "Date"=>"2013-04-05 14:35:29", "Duration"=>"0:00:24", "Call Type"=>"Incoming"}, 
{"name"=>"Henry Jones ", "Date"=>"2013-04-05 15:54:53", "Duration"=>"0:00:00", "Call Type"=>"Missed"}, 
{"name"=>"Henry Jones ", "Date"=>"2013-04-06 16:21:20", "Duration"=>"0:00:47", "Call Type"=>"Outgoing"}
]
```

I would like to group_by the date of the date string (e.g."2013-04-06") I can group_by the whole date string by using `array_of_hashes.group_by {|d| d["Date"] }` however this takes the whole string.

How can I just group on the date excluding the time?
TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there.  Since the date is separated from the time by a space, you can use [String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-split) to divide the date from the time, and then [Array#first](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-first) to get the date:

```
array_of_hashes.group_by do |hash|
  hash['Date'].split.first
end
```

Using IRB, you can see how this works:

```
$ irb
2.0.0p0 :001 > date = "2013-04-06 16:21:20"
 => "2013-04-06 16:21:20" 
2.0.0p0 :002 > date.split
 => ["2013-04-06", "16:21:20"] 
2.0.0p0 :003 > date.split.first
 => "2013-04-06"
```

Comment: Thanks Wayne. Simple, elegant and much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The value for `Date` is just a string. Luckily it's a well-behaved, fixed-width, sortable string. The first 10 chars are what we want:

```
array=[
{"name"=>"Henry Jones ", "Date"=>"2013-04-09 15:09:02", "Duration"=>"0:00:00", "Call Type"=>"Outgoing"},
{"name"=>"Barry Smith ", "Date"=>"2013-04-08 13:51:03", "Duration"=>"0:00:48", "Call Type"=>"Incoming"}, 
{"name"=>"Henry Jones ", "Date"=>"2013-04-04 19:30:19", "Duration"=>"0:00:49", "Call Type"=>"Outgoing"},
{"name"=>"Alistair Morgan ", "Date"=>"2013-04-05 13:14:07", "Duration"=>"0:00:03", "Call Type"=>"Outgoing"}, 
{"name"=>"Quentin Blah", "Date"=>"2013-04-05 13:19:44", "Duration"=>"0:04:28", "Call Type"=>"Missed"}, 
{"name"=>"Quentin Blah", "Date"=>"2013-04-05 13:25:19", "Duration"=>"0:09:45", "Call Type"=>"Incoming"}, 
{"name"=>"Henry Jones ", "Date"=>"2013-04-05 14:35:29", "Duration"=>"0:00:24", "Call Type"=>"Incoming"}, 
{"name"=>"Henry Jones ", "Date"=>"2013-04-05 15:54:53", "Duration"=>"0:00:00", "Call Type"=>"Missed"}, 
{"name"=>"Henry Jones ", "Date"=>"2013-04-06 16:21:20", "Duration"=>"0:00:47", "Call Type"=>"Outgoing"}
] 

p array.group_by{|call| call["Date"][0..9]}
```

Comment: BTW do you know Ruby creates an object for each appearance of the string "name", "Date" etc? Symbols could save you some memory.